# Trying to mock my static method and need to return an object, but it object always returning null

Tags: java, junit, mocking

Here is my code

```
@Test

public void testProcess() throws Exception {

    GenericResults result = new GenericResults();
    result.setCount(2);
    result.setSuccess(true);
    result.setTarget((Integer)100);

PowerMockito.when(PrcssDAO.createProcess(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(result);

}
```

The `result` object that is returned is always null. Why is this?

Comment: Did you include the proper Annotations on your class? Notably _@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)_ and _@PrepareForTest(PrcssDAO.class)_.

Basically, could you show us the rest of your code.

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PrcssDAO.class, SysParamDAO.class})
public class SVSCommEvntManagerTest {  @Test

public void testProcess() throws Exception {

    GenericResults result = new GenericResults();
    result.setCount(2);
    result.setSuccess(true);
    result.setTarget((Integer)100);

PowerMockito.when(PrcssDAO.createProcess(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(result);

}

Answer (score 1):

did you considered these steps inside your test class :

1. Use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the
   class-level of the test case.
2. Use the `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)`
   annotation at the class-level of the test case.
3. Use `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to
   mock all methods of this class.
4. Use `PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to change
   the class to replay mode.
5. Use `PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to change
   the class to verify mode.

here's the [source](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

Comment: Yes I have using all above thing. I missed to mention in my question

Answer (score 0):

OK, I copied your code locally to figure it out, what you need to make it work is to add option three of the above mentioned answer to your code, so the code of the test would then become:

```
@Test
public void testProcess() throws Exception {
    GenericResults result = new GenericResults();
    result.setCount(2);
    result.setSuccess(true);
    result.setTarget(100);
        // The next line is the one you're missing
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PrcssDAO.class);
    Mockito.when(PrcssDAO.createProcess(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(result);
    assertNotNull(PrcssDAO.createProcess("any", "argument"));
}
```